# Using if statement on data-bind text

Tags: knockout.js

I can not quite figure out how to put an if statement inside a `text` binding.

```html
<tbody data-bind="foreach: model.poCollection">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td data-bind="text: RlseNbr"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Clin"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: PrchOrdNbr"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: RqstnCntrlNbr"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: {(DtCntrctDlvry == '0') ? 'a' :'b'}"></td>
    </tr>
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong the moment I attempt to put the if statement in it the data is no longer displayed.

Comment: Try with `text: DtCntrctDlvry() == '0' ? 'a' :'b'`

Comment: To expand on @nemesv's comment. If `DtCntrctDlvry` (crazy name btw) is an observable, then it's never going to equal `'0'` because observables aren't strings, they're observables. Get the backing value by calling the observable as a function and then compare that with `'0'`.

Comment: @nemevs +1. Another way: text: ko.unwrap(DtCntrctDlvry) == '0' ? 'a' :'b'

Comment: @TSV's approach is preferred when you don't know at runtime if a property is an observable or not.

Comment: One more option if you don't want to have to worry about these syntax issues as often. http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2013/05/20/knockout-es5-a-plugin-to-simplify-your-syntax/

Comment: thanks that got it working I made a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26399/   If you put your suggestion as an answer I can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You haven't provided enough info, but we can safely assume one of two situations:

1. Plain properties: `DtCntrctDlvry = 0`; or
2. Observables: `DtCntrctDlvry = ko.observable(0)`

Binding handlers don't care which it is if you do *simple* bindings, e.g.:

```html
<span data-bind="text: DtCntrctDlvry"></span>
```

But they *do* care if you start putting logic in there. Above situations respectively require:

1. Plain properties:

   ```html
   <span data-bind="text: DtCntrctDlvry === 0 ? 'a' : 'b'"></span>
   ```
2. Observables:

   ```html
   <span data-bind="text: DtCntrctDlvry() === 0 ? 'a' : 'b'"></span>
   ```

In any case, please see [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32255456/419956) where I argue that you would be off even better if you wrap the logic inside a `computed`, e.g.:

```javascript
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.DtCntrctDlvry = ko.observable(0);
  self.DtCntrctDlvryText = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.DtCntrctDlvry() === 0 ? "a" : "b";
  });
}
```

And bind like this:

```html
<span data-bind="text: DtCntrctDlvryText"></span>
```

---

PS. Some footnotes:

1. Do you realize you're using `==` where you might prefer `===`?
2. Any reason you're writing `'0'` (zero, but as a string) instead of `0` (as a number)?

In my answer I've assumed the for both cases you meant to use the latter. If not, you may have to tweak my solution for that.

Comment: You can use **ko.unwrap** to avoid the issue of plain properties and observables

Comment: this really helped me also! 
what made it weird is the difference `()` can make. :D

Comment: @AceMark Observables are _functions_. Called without parameters they are a "*getter*", called with _one_ parameter they are a "*setter*". Only in 'simple' bindings can you leave them off because Knockout will infer them.